# I'm trying to find an attribute using simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a simpleXML output of:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
    (
        [version] => 2
    )
    [currentTime] => 2013-02-05 21:26:09
    [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [rowset] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [name] => characters
                [key] => characterID
                [columns] => name,characterID,corporationName,corporationID
            )
            [row] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Wrytha Cy
                        [characterID] => 209668693
                        [corporationName] => Deep Core Mining Inc.
                        [corporationID] => 1000006
                    )
                )
                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Eve Mae
                        [characterID] => 624980803
                        [corporationName] => Viziam
                        [corporationID] => 1000066
                    )
                )
                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Wrytha
                        [characterID] => 709227913
                        [corporationName] => The Flying Tigers
                        [corporationID] => 669350666
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [cachedUntil] => 2013-02-05 21:35:04
)
```

I would like to loop through with my php loop and get "name' and "characterID". I've trying something like:

```
    $simpleXML = simplexml_load_string($xml); 

    foreach ($simpleXML->result->rowset->row as $row) {
        print_r($row);
        $name = $row['@attributes']['name'];
        echo $name.'<br>';
    }
```

but $name is not being set. It's gonna be something simple, just not seeing it in my haste and first time with simpleXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are accessed using the syntax `$element['attribute_name']`, so in your case, you need `$row['name']`.

It's important to remember that SimpleXML objects are kind of magic - the `$element->child`, `$element_list[0]` and `$element['foo']` syntax overloads the normal PHP logic to be useful. Similarly, `(string)$element` will give you the full textual content of an element, however it is broken up in the actual XML.

As such, the `print_r` output will not give you a "real" view of the object, so should be used with care. There are [a couple of alternative debug functions I've written here](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) which give a more accurate idea of how the object will behave.